# Compare two nodes based on child nodes from different xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XMLs :-

1. keylist.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jdbcGeneralActivityOutput>
   <unknownResultset>
       <row>
           <column>
               <name>SRC_SYS_ID</name>
               <value>10015</value>
           </column>
           <column>
               <name>SRC_SYS_RCRD_ID_VAL</name>
               <value>3327853</value>
           </column>
       </row>
       <row>
           <column>
               <name>SRC_SYS_ID</name>
               <value>10015</value>
           </column>
           <column>
               <name>SRC_SYS_RCRD_ID_VAL</name>
               <value>9751818</value>
           </column>
       </row>
       <row>
           <column>
               <name>SRC_SYS_ID</name>
               <value>10015</value>
           </column>
           <column>
               <name>SRC_SYS_RCRD_ID_VAL</name>
               <value>9883123</value>
           </column>
       </row>
       <row>
           <column>
               <name>SRC_SYS_ID</name>
               <value>10015</value>
           </column>
           <column>
               <name>SRC_SYS_RCRD_ID_VAL</name>
               <value>9901061</value>
           </column>
       </row>
   </unknownResultset>    </jdbcGeneralActivityOutput>
   ```

and the second XML 
2. CurrentRow.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
    <column>
        <name>SRC_SYS_ID</name>
        <value>10015</value>
    </column>
    <column>
        <name>SRC_SYS_RCRD_ID_VAL</name>
        <value>3327853</value>
    </column>
    <column>
        <name>PRTY_STTS_CDV</name>
        <value>A</value>
    </column>
    <column>
        <name>PRTY_DSPLY_NM</name>
        <value>ALEGRIA BRAZILIAN GRILL</value>
    </column>
    <column>
        <name>ADDR_LN_1_TXT</name>
        <value>24449 KATY FRWY SUITE 500</value>
    </column>
    <column>
        <name>ADDR_LN_2_TXT</name>
        <value/>
    </column>
    <column>
        <name>ADDR_LN_3_TXT</name>
        <value/>
    </column>
</row>
```

What I want to do is to find out if either of the complete row(all the name value pairs within a row should match) in keylist.xml is present in currentRow.xml or not.

This is what I tried so far..but no luck. Can anyone please help me

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="currentRow" select="document('C:\Personal\09086559\Desktop\Xmls\currentRow.xml')"/>
    <!--<xsl:param name="TargetPrimaryKeys" select="document('C:\Personal\09086559\Desktop\Xmls\temp5.xml')"/>
    -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="jdbcGeneralActivityOutput/unknownResultset/row">
            <xsl:for-each select="column">
                <xsl:variable name="currentName" select="current()/name"/>
                <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="current()/value"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$currentRow/row/column">
                    <xsl:if test="current()/name=$currentName and current()/value=$currentValue">Y</xsl:if>
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="$currentName"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue"/>
                    -->
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you clarify (a) which document is being processed by the XSLT, and (b) what is the expected result?

Comment: the keylist.xml is processed by XSLT and currentRow.xml is passed as parameter, but that is open and if needed I can reverse that as well.The expected output in above case should be just "Y" as both the columns(name/value)  present in first <row> of keylist.xml are available in currentRow.xml as well.If none of the <row> matches then I am expecting output as "N"

Comment: So there is just a single global "yes" or "no" result for the entire input?

Comment: yes. Just want to find out if any of the row from keylist.xml is present in currentRow.xml or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vivek original answer seems to be OK.  You can  changed for-each to apply-templates and modified output to something more clear than Y. The program is just comparing all elements *column* from two XMLs to find if they are identical.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="column">
<xsl:variable name="currantName" select="name"/>
<xsl:variable name="currantValue" select="value"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="document('currentNode.xml')//column"><!--modify your PATH to currentNode.xml-->
 <xsl:if test="(./name/text() = $currantName) and (./value/text() = $currantValue) ">
 YES, found the element
 <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
from  currentNode.xml   in keylist.xml.
 </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
<root>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
Search is over. All possible matches should be listed above.
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentRow" select="document('C:\Personal\09086559\Desktop\Xmls\currentRow.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="col" match="column" use="concat(name, '|', value)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="keyvals">
        <xsl:for-each select="$currentRow/row/column">
            <keyval><xsl:value-of select="concat(name, '|', value)" /></keyval>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="key('col', exsl:node-set($keyvals)/keyval)">yes</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>no</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

If I understand your clarification correctly, i.e that "yes" means there is at least one row whose columns all have a matching column in the other document, then try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentRow" select="document('C:\Personal\09086559\Desktop\Xmls\currentRow.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="keyvals">
        <xsl:for-each select="$currentRow/row/column">
            <keyval><xsl:value-of select="concat(name, '|', value)" /></keyval>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="jdbcGeneralActivityOutput/unknownResultset/row[count(column) = count(column[concat(name, '|', value)=exsl:node-set($keyvals)/keyval])]">yes</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>no</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, but I am getting this error "Namespace 'http://exslt.org/common' does not contain any functions"  Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Vivek, which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: I changed to saxon-B and was able to run it, however I am always getting no as output.

Comment: I got what is going wrong, the output is coming as yes even if one of the name/value pair from keylist is present in current row. What I wanted was that it should give yes only when all the name/value pairs of <row> in keylist.xml  are present in <row> of currentRow.xml

Comment: @Vivek Which one is it? "*Just want to find out if **any** of the row from keylist.xml is present in currentRow.xml or not*" **OR**  "*it should give yes only when **all** the name/value pairs of <row> in keylist.xml are present in <row> of currentRow.xml*"

Comment: In the above example, the two name/value pairs present in  first row of keylist.xml are also present in currentRow.xml, so for the above two xmls output should be "yes", but if in above keylist.xml if you change value 3327853 to 3327854 and run the xslt then output should be "no"